# How to create object's download link in AmazonS3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Am using below third party API in my project development
http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class

I have done all task like upload, delete, bucket-list, object-list with this API,
but one of major task to create object download link form a bucket is hazy.

Official Amazon API has :
`get_object_url ( $bucket, $filename, $preauth, $opt )`
to get any object's URL, but with above API is lack of method and documentation.

Its shows following error with this code when i click on download link:

**Code**

```
<h1>All uploaded files</h1>
<?php
    // Get the contents of our bucket
    $contents = $s3->getBucket("mybucket");
    foreach ($contents as $file){

        $fname = $file['name'];
        $furl = "http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/".$fname;

        //output a link to the file
        echo "<a href=\"$furl\">$fname</a><br />";
    }
?>
```

**Error**

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
 <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
 <Message>Access Denied</Message>
 <RequestId>5A23C56B55611736</RequestId>
 <HostId>m2V2NlI19zgGPq0o4lXmIfod2BeQZIkuH4Yu651372cE/hfa9BkLdV8y3LlYjtw1</HostId>
</Error>
```

If someone has any idea or experience with this API then suggest me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you are using : http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class S3 class, and want to create download link of an object from bucket

You should try this:

```
$s3 = new S3($aws_access_key, $aws_secret_key);

$url = $s3->getAuthenticatedURL($aws_bucket_name, $file_name, 3600));

echo "<a href='$url' target='_blank'>Download</a>";
```

This download link will expire after 1hr(3600sec.), you can extend expire time by the last parameter to increment it.

Comment: I have updated my S3 class - 
`Link: http://amazon-s3-php-class.googlecode.com/files/s3-php5-curl_0.4.0.tar.gz`

Answer (score 0):

Does all files have all user read permission (public accessible) ?

if you want to access that file without authenticated way then you have to give read permission to that file. else you can also create signed url.

Comment: Yep
`Grantee: Frank
Open/Download: Yes
View Permissions:Yes
Edit Permissions:Yes`